# Why compiler says that " possible lossy conversion from int to byte" for this java code ?

Tags: java, byte

When I tried to run this code in an online java compiler it says "**possible lossy conversion from int to byte**". But i can't understand the meaning of this message. Badly need help. I am a beginner at Java.

```
class HelloWorld{   
         public static void main(String args[]){
             byte b=9;
             b+=6;
             System.out.println(b);
             b=b+5;
             System.out.println(b);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When execute `b + 5`, `b` will be promoted to `int`, and the result will be `int`.

When you reassign this `byte` with this `int`, it might loss accuracy.